# Fitting custom regression equation with data in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

Let say I have below data

```
  library(zoo)
  Dates = seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2005-12-31'), by = '6 months')
  Data = rbind(data.frame(time = Dates, y = rnorm(length(Dates), 0, 10), month = as.factor(format(Dates, '%m')), type = 'A', M = log(12+0:11)),
                data.frame(time = Dates, y = rnorm(length(Dates), 0, 10), month = as.factor(format(Dates, '%m')), type = 'B', M = log(3+0:11)),
                data.frame(time = Dates, y = rnorm(length(Dates), 0, 10), month = as.factor(format(Dates, '%m')), type = 'C', M = log(2+0:11)),
                data.frame(time = Dates[3:10], y = rnorm(8, 0, 10), month = as.factor(format(Dates[3:10], '%m')), type = 'D', M = log(10+0:7)))
  XX = zoo(rt(length(Dates), 2, 0), Dates)
```

And a hypothetical model

```
y[t, type] = Beta[0] + Beta[1] * xx[t] + Beta[2] * type + Beta[3] * month + Beta[4] * M[t, type] + error
```

I am trying to use `lm()` function to estimate the parameters of above model, given the data, but not sure how to fit above equation in `lm()` function.

Is it possible to use `lm()` function for above model? What are other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a particularly unusual model specification. You want:

```
y[t, type] = Beta[0] + Beta[1] * xx[t] + Beta[2] * type + 
    Beta[3] * month + Beta[4] * M[t, type] + error
```

Given the way your data are set up, you can think of this as indexing by `i`:

```
y[t[i], type[i]] = ... Beta[1] * xx[t[i]] + Beta[2] * type[i] + ... +
    Beta[4]* M[t[i], type[i]] ...
```

Which corresponds to this formula in `lm` (the `1` stands for the intercept/`Beta[0]` term, which will be added by default in any case unless you add `0` or `-1` to your formula).

```r
y ~ 1 + xx + type + month + M
```

The one thing that doesn't match your desired specification is that, because `type` is a *categorical* variable (factor) with more than two levels, there won't be a single parameter `Beta[2]`: instead, R will internally convert `type` to a series of `(n_level-1)` dummy variables (search for questions/material about "contrasts" to understand this process) better).

Comment: Thanks. So I need to merge `Data` and `xx` to get complete data matrix to use for `data` argument in `lm()` - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.